# jQuery - Dynamically added content - Radio on change function

Tags: jquery

I am using Ajax to load a popup containing different settings, including a button ("click" event) and some radio buttons ("change" event).

While the "click" event works fine, (using the following function)

```
$("#my_popup").on("click", '.my_button', function() {  
   "use strict";
   // do some things
});
```

... the "change" event does not. See the corresponding function below:

```
$('#my_popup').on('change', 'input[name=input_name]:radio', function(){
  "use strict";

  if(condition) {
    // do some other things

  } else {
    // do some other things
  }

});
```

Any ideas how to make this work? According to the dynamic event binding rules [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements) I believe it should be working fine...

HTML:

```
<div id="my_popup">    
  <input id="radio_1" type="radio" name="input_name">
  <input id="radio_2" type="radio" name="input_name">

  <!-- [...] -->
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: this isnt proper syntax `if(condition).val()) {`. additionally, can you tell what does happen? console errors, function never gets called, etc. is `input[name=input_name]:radio` a valid selector? it doesnt look like one. can you give the radios a class and see if it works then

Comment: sorry for that, just wanted to clean it before posting and forgot removing the ".val()". No, no console errors. It seems like the function does indeed never get called!

Comment: No HTML given so we can't see that your selector is correct

Comment: Could you include your html?

Comment: Are you setting up your click handler prior to the ajax call? If those items don't exist in the DOM at the time you apply the click handler it won't work. You need to apply the click handler after the ajax call.

Comment: @Jage as you can see the bindings are delegated so will work on future elements.

Comment: The given code works fine. https://jsfiddle.net/nmw4e0v1/

Comment: @Popnoodles - this way it does, but the HTML content within #my_popup is added dynamically via Ajax.

Comment: @Jage - both the "click" and the "change" functions are set up prior to the ajax call. And strangely only the "click" handler works.

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: @Mortimer Given code works with dynamically added elements too https://jsfiddle.net/nmw4e0v1/2/

Comment: @Popnoodles - thanks, I'll check again for any mistakes in my code.

Comment: @tnschmidt - jquery-1.11.3.min.js

Comment: @Mortimer maybe post the whole code within that anon function?

Comment: @Popnoodles - I just found out that the "change" function - oddly - prevents the radio buttons from being changed (checked).

Comment: @Popnoodles, also this function works just fine when I replace "change" with "click"